# Sorting words in a sentence

Tags: python

iv attached a screenshot of my probem.  my code in atom is the same from the book yet i keep getting the same error no matter what i change. it changes but same did you mean sort_words? changed a few lines to sort_words yet same outcome. can anyone shed any light please

my code below and link to the output below this.

```
def break_words(stuff):
  """ this function will break up words for us."""
  words = stuff.split(' ')
  return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print(word)

def print_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print(word)

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = sort_words(sentence)
    return sorted_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """prints the first and last words of the sentence"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: `return sorted_words(words)` Where did you make a `sorted_words()` function? Same here `return sorted(words)`.

Comment: you call `sorted_words(words)` but your function is called `sort_words` so in `sort_sentence` you must call `return sort_words(words)`

Comment: You have no function named `sorted_words()`, why are you trying to call it with `return sorted_words(words)`? You already sorted the words on the previous line.

Comment: The problem is the line `return sorted_words(words)` in `sort_sentence`

Comment: The error message even suggests the alternative function.

Comment: Note: you may wish to accommodate odd spacing by using a regular expression. `re.split(r'\s+', sentence)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in `sort_sentence`:

1. It receives a string as an argument, so it needs to split it into words using `break_words()`.
2. It's calling `sorted_words()` when the name of the function is `sort_words()`.

```
def sort_sentence(sentence):
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)
```